# How to map my stored procedure result in my class

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have 3 tables in SQL Server. The first one is for orders, the second one is for order line items, and the third one is for order logs.

This is the diagram of my database:

[text](https://ibb.co/jGdX1Fm)

This is my SQL Server stored procedure query:

```
SELECT 
    table1.ID AS OrderID,
    table1.Account,
    table1.OrderNumber,
    table2.OrderID AS OrderLineItemID,
    table2.ID, table2.Price,
    orderlog.ID AS OrderLogID,
    orderlog.OrderLog
FROM 
    [dbo].[Order] AS table1
LEFT JOIN 
    OrderLineItems AS table2 ON table1.ID = table2.OrderID
LEFT JOIN 
    [dbo].[OrderLog] AS orderlog ON table1.ID = orderlog.OrderID 
WHERE
    table1.ID = @orderID
```

Below is attached a picture of the result whenever the stored procedure executed the result.

[text](https://ibb.co/TvLQ6gN)

This is my `OrderView` class:

```
public class OrderView
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string OrderNumber { get; set; }
    public string Account { get; set; }
    public  List<OrderLineItem> OrderLineItems { get; set; }
    public  List<OrderLog> OrderLogs { get; set; }
}
```

How can I make this happen so that whenever it calls the stored procedure to fetch the record, it maps to my class without using loop? I'm using Entity Framework with a database-first approach in ASP.NET MVC 5.

Comment: use [dapper](https://www.learndapper.com/)

Comment: I would fill a datatable instead of class.  See : https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Load-Fill-Populate-DataTable-from-Stored-Procedure-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

Comment: @MohammadAghazadeh is there any alternate way other than dapper because my project is based on entity framework.

Comment: EF can't populate an object graph (=objects with nested objects) from a stored-procedure result. Only `Include` does that.

Answer (score 0):

I reckon you can either use `MapToStoredProcedures()` like:

```cs
public class OrderView
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string OrderNumber { get; set; }
    public string Account { get; set; }
    public List<OrderLineItem> OrderLineItems { get; set; }
    public List<OrderLog> OrderLogs { get; set; }
}

public class OrderLineItem
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}

public class OrderLog
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    public string OrderLog { get; set; }
}

public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<OrderView> OrderViews { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<OrderView>().MapToStoredProcedures();
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

or you can use `Database.SqlQuery<T>`

```cs
public IEnumerable<OrderView> GetOrderView(int orderID)
{
    var parameters = new SqlParameter[] {
        new SqlParameter("@orderID", orderID)
    };
    
    var result = this.Database.SqlQuery<OrderView>(
        "EXEC dbo.MyStoredProcedure @orderID",
        parameters);
    
    return result.ToList();
}
```

Comment: I have executed  GetOrderView method, and it’s showing null in order line items and order logs.

I'm using a database-first approach in ASP.Net MVC 5, and the entity version framework is 6.0.

This is a picture of my result.  [Image](https://ibb.co/nb7mbdv)